# How can I transform 2D OSM Polygon to 3D when I have a height value attribute?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap, geojson, gdal

I have an OSM database with only buildings polygons and its height attribute. I've deleted anything without height.

Now I need to convert the "way" column to 3D (or create another column I don't know) to convert all plain 2D polys to 3D geometries, setting the height attribute to the "Z" coordinate value.

I can't find any PostGIS function to do this (or I couldn't interpret the ones that exist).

Is there any way to do this or do I need GDAL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [`ST_DumpPoints`](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113029/polygon-from-line-creation-problem) your geometry, add the `Z` dimension to with [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) and create the Polygon again, e.g.

```
WITH j (geom,height) AS (
 SELECT 
  (ST_DumpPoints('POLYGON((30 10,40 40,20 40,10 20,30 10))'::geometry)).geom,42
)
SELECT 
ST_AsText(
 ST_MakePolygon(
  ST_MakeLine(
   ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom),height))))
FROM j;

                         st_astext                          
------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((30 10 42,40 40 42,20 40 42,10 20 42,30 10 42))
(1 Zeile)
```

In the end, creating a new column or updating an existing one is up to you.

I admit this is not a very elegant solution. I'd be definitely glad if our fellow PostGIS experts can come up with a better one.

If you already have all 3 dimensions in your polygon and just want to change the geometry to the proper type, take a look at [`ST_Force3D`](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_Force_3D.html):

```
SELECT 
ST_AsText(
 ST_Force3D('POLYGON((30 10 42,40 40 42,20 40 42,10 20 42,30 10 42))'::geometry));

                         st_astext                          
------------------------------------------------------------
 POLYGON Z ((30 10 42,40 40 42,20 40 42,10 20 42,30 10 42))
(1 Zeile)
```

**EDIT**: This is the answer in OSM context kindly provided by @Magno C:

First you need to convert the "height" attribute column to "real" because OSM data is only text. But first you need to delete all non-number data. You may delete all `null` lines too. Be advised you WILL loose data!

```
alter table planet_osm_polygon add column alt real;
delete from planet_osm_polygon where height !~ '^([0-9]+[.]?[0-9]*|[.][0-9]+)$'
update planet_osm_polygon set alt = CAST ( REPLACE(height,',','.') AS real);
```

Now, you need to force the LineStrings to be closed. I follow [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113029/polygon-from-line-creation-problem) and create the `ST_ForceClosed` function.

Now the above mentioned answer can work. I modify it to conform the OSM table structure.

```
ALTER TABLE planet_osm_polygon ADD COLUMN buildings3d geometry;
```

and

```
WITH j (geom,height) AS (
  SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(way::geometry)).geom, alt from planet_osm_polygon
)
update planet_osm_polygon set buildings3d = ( SELECT 
 ST_MakePolygon( ( ST_ForceClosed( ST_MakeLine( ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom),ST_Y(geom),height) ) ) ) ) 
FROM j );
```

Further reading: [`ST_MakeLine`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) and [`ST_MakePolygon`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePolygon.html)

Comment: Seems your solution is working until now. I'm in trouble with the "height" column content for now but I think ( elegant or not ) this will work for me. Wait a minute and I'll post the result. I'm converting your solution to use OSM data ( select from planet_osm_polygon and so on...).

Comment: Just to know the "height" column have a lot of junk and needs some work to adjust. May loose some data ...

Comment: So perhaps you should clean up the height column before running your update :D I'm unfortunately unaware of a function that adds `Z` dimensions to geometries to make the code shorter. 
Saudacoes pro meu amado Brasil! (we're not supposed to write PT here ;-)

Comment: This should be an "one step conversion" and elegancy is not my concern. Valeu Jim! Não se preocupe com a coluna height.

Comment: I would also take the same approach :) +1 for the quick responses

Comment: Well... after correcting the "height" column ( and lost more 350 polygons ) I'm facing the follow problem: seems the LineString shell cannot be closed in some cases: `lwpoly_from_lwlines: shell must be closed SQL state: XX000`. Working on this...

Comment: Oh ok. Are there also MultiPolygons in your column? You could also add the polygons that are causing this problem to your question and I can take a look later today. Good luck!

Comment: Don't know... The OSM data are veeery big... may be.

Comment: Good enough! Thanks. Now I'm waiting (possibly for hours) to query to complete.